# Записать номер массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, frontend

```
var arrmain = 
    [ 
      "https://www.youtube.com/embed/jmfHK0v15Ok",
      "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9syXx2nza_w"
    ];

var link1;
link1 = [Math.floor(Math.random()*arrmain.length)];
```

Каким образом можно записать номер массива из этого участка кода?

Comment: что такое номер массива? опишите что вы хотите получить.

Comment: *Номер элемента массива. В данном случае в массиве два элемента. [0] и [1]. С помощью Math floor мы получаем рандомный элемент массива.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrmain = 
    [ 
      "https://www.youtube.com/embed/jmfHK0v15Ok",
      "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9syXx2nza_w"
    ];

var link1, nomermassiva;
nomermassiva = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrmain.length);
link1 = arrmain[nomermassiva];
```